# How I update data in push_array data in livewire or laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

How I update data in push_array data in livewire or laravel see the array data bellow. I try it but not success Just I want to update data who's I push in array with array_push()

```
  array:6 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 0
    "input_Data" => "Up to 15 Groups / Month"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "input_Data" => "Up to 60 CSV File Importing / Month"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "input_Data" => "Up to 15 SMTP Config"
  ]
  3 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 3
    "input_Data" => "Up to 20 Email Template Can Make"
  ]
  4 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 4
    "input_Data" => "Up to 150 Ai Writer Call / Month"
  ]
  5 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 5
    "input_Data" => "Markitach SMTP Limit 1000 Emails"
  ]
  ]
```

I want to update input_Data where id 3, How can I do it. please help me.

I try it but can't success :(

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = [
    0 => [
        "id"         => 0,
        "input_Data" => "Up to 15 Groups / Month"
    ],
    1 => [
        "id"         => 1,
        "input_Data" => "Up to 60 CSV File Importing / Month"
    ],
    2 => [
        "id"         => 2,
        "input_Data" => "Up to 15 SMTP Config"
    ],
    3 => [
        "id"         => 3,
        "input_Data" => "Up to 20 Email Template Can Make"
    ],
    4 => [
        "id"         => 4,
        "input_Data" => "Up to 150 Ai Writer Call / Month"
    ],
    5 => [
        "id"         => 5,
        "input_Data" => "Markitach SMTP Limit 1000 Emails"
    ]
];
foreach ($data as $key => $aData) {
    if ($aData['id'] == 3) {
        $data[$key]['input_Data'] = 'data changed';
    }
}
```

Comment: If the index of data is always the same as id then you can simply write $data[3]['input_Data'] = 'data changed';

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).